# How should I ask for permission to adapt a copyrighted work for non-commercial purposes?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I‘m part of a small group of hobbyist producing an audio play podcast for fun. We don‘t make any revenue - no ads, no donations, no fees, no affiliate links. We have around 600 listeners.

Now we have come across a novella from the 60s which we would like to adapt into an audio play. The copyright owners seem to be the author‘s heirs, represented by an estate representative.

What would be a good way to ask the rights holders for permission?

Comment: Send them an email. Start off with a formal greeting, then paste in the first 2 lines of this exact question. Finish off by asking if you may use their material for your podcast. Then sign-off. very simple.

Answer (score 2):

I do X and I really enjoyed your novella Y. I would like to adapt it for the podcast. Please contact me so we can explore licensing options. Thank you and have a nice day.